# How to understand Exponential Shadow Mapping in HLSL with Directional Light?

Tags: xna, monogame, hlsl

I've tried to understand how ESM is working - I have regular Shadow Mapping in Place (occluded/not occluded) in a deferred rendering pipeline and are trying to use ESM instead.

I've tried to adapt this from Cansin:
[http://homepage.lnu.se/staff/tblma/Deferred Rendering in XNA 4.pdf](http://homepage.lnu.se/staff/tblma/Deferred%20Rendering%20in%20XNA%204.pdf)

But as he does not use directional lights, I may have a misunderstanding. This is basically my approach on adapting it to directional lights:

*Create ShadowMap*:

```
float4 PS(VSO input) : COLOR0
{
    float depth = input.Position2D.z / input.Position2D.w;
    return exp(depth);
}
```

I am using an Orthogonal Projection Matrix (same NearFarClip as actual cam), as I do with regular Shadow Mapping (Position2D is ScreenSpace, because it's a directional light, Z is always the distance surface/light, or am I wrong?)

*Get Shadow Factor* - basically like regular Shadow Mapping, I transform into Light/Screenspace, getting the depth from the ShadowMap

```
float4 Position = 1;
Position.xy = input.ScreenPosition.xy;
Position.z = Depth; // saved depth from gbuffer
Position = mul(Position, InverseViewProjection);
Position /= Position.w;

float4 LightScreenPos = mul(Position, LightViewProjection);
LightScreenPos /= LightScreenPos.w;

float2 LUV = 0.5f * (float2(LightScreenPos.x, -LightScreenPos.y) + 1.0f);

float shadowDepth = tex2D(sampler_shadow, LUV).r;

float shadow = shadowDepth * exp(-10 * LightScreenPos.z);
```

Is my thinking fundamentally wrong?